# Can i use openUI5 to develop web app unrelated from SAP system?

Tags: web-applications, sapui5

I have to develop a simple webapp ***not connected to any SAP system***.
Can i use openUI5 to do this?

I searched online a lot, but couldn't find any answers.

It's a simple site with user authentication for 
exchanging item

Can i use MySQL to manage data? (items and users information)
How can i manage users authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use it. Also you can use it in commercial app. Yes you can use any DB, sql or no-sql dbs. UI5 built-in support oData, I prefer use it as rest protocol.
We create [SaaS](http://emutabakat.isisbilisim.com.tr/) project with C# .Net backend.
Also there are boiler plate projects for UI5, may be you can start with them.